# Use node-http-proxy in fastify `Error: socket hang up`

Tags: node.js

I'm using the node-http-proxy library to create a forward proxy server. I eventually plan to use some middleware to modify the html code on the fly. This is how my proxy server code looks like

```
fastify v3.2.1
http-proxy v1.18.1
```

```js
const fastify = require('fastify')();
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

fastify.post('/', (request, reply) => {
    proxy.web(request.raw, reply.raw,
        {
            target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8084/a-node/demo',
            ignorePath: true
        },
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reply.raw.statusCode = 500;
                reply.raw.end('Error');
            }
        });
});

fastify.listen(9103);
```

POST requests to my server appear to just hang, and never arrive at the target server.